# While compile : Creation table error

Tags: java, android, sql

While compiling, this error shows:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEnewtable": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEnewtable{id INTEGER PRIMERY KEY, editname TEXT, edittel TEXT, editskype TEXT, editaddress TEXT }.

```
public class DataManipulator {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "newtable";
    private static Context context;
    static SQLiteDatabase db;
    private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
    private static final String INSERT = "insert into" +TABLE_NAME+ "(editname, edittel, editskype, 
    editaddress) values(?,?,?,?)";
    public DataManipulator(Context context)
    {
        DataManipulator.context = context; 
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulator.context);
        DataManipulator.db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.insertStmt = DataManipulator.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    }

    public long insert(String editname, String edittel, String editskype, String editaddress)
    {
        this.insertStmt.bindString(1, editname);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(2, edittel);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(3, editskype);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(4, editaddress);
        return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteAll()
    {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public List<String[]> selectAll()
    {
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"id","editname", "edittel", "editskype", 
        "editaddress"},null, null, null, null, "name asc");
        int x=0;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                String[] bb= new String[] { 
            cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4)};
                list.add(bb);
                x=x+1;
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
        {
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }

    public void delete(int rowId)
    {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        OpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" +TABLE_NAME+ "{id INTEGER PRIMERY KEY, editname TEXT, edittel TEXT, editskype TEXT, editaddress TEXT }");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check your `SQL` syntax

Comment: Your syntax error is caused by a missing space after "CREATE TABLE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this :**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+ "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, editname TEXT, edittel TEXT, editskype TEXT, editaddress TEXT )");
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of basic SQL syntax problems. Please consider learning some basic SQL and stacktrace reading first.

1. Add whitespace between SQL keywords such as `TABLE` and identifiers such as `newtable`.

   For example, change

   ```
   "CREATE TABLE" +TABLE_NAME+
   ```

   to

   ```
    "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+
   ```

   and

   ```
    "insert into" +TABLE_NAME+
   ```

   to

   ```
    "insert into " +TABLE_NAME+
   ```
2. The parentheses in `CREATE TABLE` should be `(` `)` and not `{` `}`
3. Typo in `PRIMERY`, should be `PRIMARY`.

Plus possibly a lots more; these are just the issues found with the first 10 seconds of looking at your SQL.